# Odoo-sh Upgrade : How to disable a view / uninstall a module during upgrade process (v13 to v15)?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, uninstallation, odoo-13, odoo-15

During the upgrade process on odoo.sh on branch BrStaging, there are errors in the log panel. Some obsolete custom Modules or Views are the cause of these errors. To disable or uninstall them, we have to use SQL queries because we cannot enter odoo which cannot start:

[image]

My Try: using in Odoo-sh> SHELL-Tab, the shell command :  psql:

- To disable a view

  ```
  UPDATE public.ir_ui_view SET active = false WHERE id = 10381;
  ```
- To disable/uninstall a module

  ```
  UPDATE ir_module_module set state='to remove'
  WHERE name in ('my_custom_module') and state='installed';
  ```
- ...have tried that request too:

  ```
  UPDATE ir_module_module set state='uninstallable'
  WHERE name in ('my_custom_module') and state='installed';
  ```

...But it does t work:  after a commit or restart (command: odoosh-restart) the related error still remains!

How to disable a view and uninstall a module during the upgrade process from v13 to v15 ??

[image]

Comment: How to perform update-request on the database used for the upgrade process ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution, I have found is using a pre-migrate.py file into one of my custom module : my_custom_module/migrations/15.0.0.0.0/pre-migrate.py
which contain the Sql query that i need to execute, to correct the upgrade-log-Error:

```py
def migrate(cr, version):    

    # TO CORRECT UPGRADE ERROR 1 : Element '<xpath expr="//xxxx">' cannot be located in parent view

    cr.execute("""
        update ir_ui_view v
        set inherit_id = NULL, mode='primary', active = false
        where
        v.id in (10563,10539)
    """)
```